# Converting pixel colors to probabilities (Python)

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, function, image-processing

I need to develop an algorithm that assigns a probability to each pixel of a picture according to its RGB color code. If the pixel is completely red the probability is one. The probability lowers the less red the pixel gets. The blue pixels should be assigned with the lowest probability. I work with python. Thanks a lot for your help!
[Color pattern of interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjUEW.png)

Comment: This is way too informal. It also seems that you are missing some knowledge about colorspaces (i'm no expert either). You did not define any info on how to interpret white / yellow for example. I think all approaches will be based on some color-space transformation and each of these will lose information. It also seems that your input is already processed and it's very bad for your task, that this kind of color-map was used instead of something with only two colors (linear! which would make it easy).

Comment: That new image looks easier, how about `p = red - blue` (offset and scaled to be in 0..1), that looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/640Qzos.png)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I changed the picture and added that the RGB color code should be processed.

Comment: Actually there's something pretty odd about that image, the "redder" parts are darker, so much so that they're actually *less res* (in the sense that their red channel value is lower than of the more white parts). They are more saturated of course. Since you can apparently change the image, can you explain how it is computed in the first place?

Comment: Here's an other attempt, based on hue and saturation: http://i.imgur.com/lEbCEVr.png

Comment: The picture is generated by the following code: `p = ax.pcolormesh(x_mat, y_mat, color_field, cmap=cm.coolwarm)`, whereby color_field contains floats between -8 and 4. Does this help?

Comment: The second approach looks really good, how does it work exactly?

Comment: Yes, you could just skip this step and generate the probabilities from `color_field`, something like `(color_field + 8) / 12` - or apply whatever mapping you want, but this way you don't have invert a mapping that isn't really known. E: my second approach was to test whether the hue is closer to red or closer to blue, if closer to blue it makes a black pixel, otherwise it multiplies the saturation by the distance from red and scales that into a valid pixel value. E2: using cm.gray would make it easy to compute from the image, if you must.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was really helpful, in all the pictures I didn't see the original problem anymore. It makes a lot of sense to work directly with the color_field values.

Answer (score 0):

RGB has 3 components: red, green, blue.

You could do it so it's: `p = Math.max(0, red - (green + blue)/2)`

If you want to discard green, `p = Math.max(0, red - blue)`.

If values are within `[0..255]` (`0x0..0xFF`) you can normalize that to the interval `[0..1]`